# Getting error: 'Could not load the specified file', when connecting to Dynamics 365 using Azure Functions 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to connect to Dynamics 365 Online using Azure Functions. I've followed a tutorial online, but these tutorials are based on Azure Functions 1.

The error I am receiving is:

```
2018-11-03T05:21:00.621 [Information] Executing 'Functions.Test' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c6ddb58b-51dc-4679-b985-4bcc7934c246)
2018-11-03T05:21:00.984 [Error] Executed 'Functions.Test' (Failed, Id=c6ddb58b-51dc-4679-b985-4bcc7934c246)
Could not load the specified file.
```

My code is as follows:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
//using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
   // log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   // dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    //name = name ?? data?.name;

   // log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

                var connectionString = @"AuthType = Office365;
                Url = https://*******.crm4.dynamics.com/;Username=******@*****;Password=****";
                CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
                                IOrganizationService service;
                service = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

                   Entity lead = new Entity("lead");
                    lead.Attributes["subject"] = "New Lead: " + name ;
                    service.Create(lead);




    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

My functions.proj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" Version="9.0.2.5"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.5.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" Version="9.0.2.7"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are problems loading assemblies as `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly` package targets at .Net Framework while your function targets at .NET Standard.

**Update**

I did it wrong, adding those assemblies to context manually doesn't work.

Without .net core sdk, we may have to give up CrmSdk and authenticate with Azure Active Directory. Note that in this way, you must have a Dynamics 365 (online) user account with System Administrator security role and the global administrator role for the Office 365 subscription.

1. Register Dynamic 365 app with Azure Active Directory. Follow these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory#prerequisites).
2. Then [authenticate using ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327838%28v%3dcrm.8%29#authenticate-using-adal).
3. Check this nuget package [Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/tree/master/dotnet), it's an API helper for working with the Common Data Service (CDS) and Dynamics 365 Web API.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work. I'm not sure what's up with this because I could swear that I have seen this implementation work seamlessly before.

Comment: @MarcusAurelio Still see `Could not load the specified file` or any other error? I managed to get rid of the error on my side but looks like assemblies are not easy to control.

Comment: That's exactly what I am seeing. In addition to the assemblies you kindly provided, I uploaded the other xrmtooling assembly. How did you manage to get rid of the error yourself?

Comment: @MarcusAurelio Sorry for my mistake, no error showed because my log streaming lost the connection so I just thought it executed without any error. I double checked the log and the error persists. I try to put the code in a .net core console app and it fails either. So lacking official .net core sdk support, using CrmSdk seems a dead end, I do some search and find we may have to use Azure AD, see my update. Not familiar with this area sorry that I am not able to test and provide detailed steps.